# Ember Model gets one update but all associations get reloaded too?

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember model with multiple hasMany relationships.

```
 App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
    drawnNumbers: DS.attr(),
    cards: DS.hasMany('card', {async: true}),
    winners: DS.hasMany('winner'),
});
```

drawnNumbers is an array with drawn numbers. When a game is playing, this array is updated every couple seconds.
My game controller looks like this:

```
drawnNumbers: function () {
    var drawnNumbers, lastNumber;

    drawnNumbers = this.get('model.drawnNumbers');
    lastNumber = drawnNumbers[drawnNumbers.length - 1];

    $("#h-cards td.number[data-number='" + lastNumber + "']").addClass('marked');
    $("#h-drawn-numbers .number[data-number='" + lastNumber + "']").addClass('active');

}.observes('model.drawnNumbers'),

ownCards: function () {
    var gameId, userId;
    gameId = this.get('id');
    userId = this.get('session.content').id;

    console.log("rerendering cards");

    return this.get('store').filter('card', function (card) {
        return (card.get('game.id') === gameId && card.get('user.id') === userId);
    });
}.property('model.cards'),
```

My problem is whenever the drawnNumbers attribute gets changed all my cards are filtered and re rendered too. This results in enormous lag since every game could have hundreds of cards.

Is there any efficient way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't filter the cards associated to your model but all the cards from the store. So I suspect that something either adds a new card to your game or that a new card is added to the store.

Your `ownCards` computed property could probably be a simple filter on the `cards` association.

```
ownCards: Ember.computed.filter('cards', function(card) {
  return card.get('user.id') === this.get('session.content.id');
})
```

Using an observer and using jquery to manually add classes in `drawnNumbers` isn't ember idiomatic. You probably should take advantage of an item controller to bind the class

See [enter link description here](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/#toc_item-controller)

Comment: Thank you. When I get home I'll check this out and let you know :)

Comment: I removed all other properties in my Game Controller but every time I receive a new number it still renders all cards again (and calls the Ember.computer.filter again too).

Comment: Can you put the code that adds a number and the payload you receive from your server?

Comment: Turns out my previous comment was false. After a hard refresh (after removing all other properties) and using my old `ownBingoCards` property it works.
Using the Ember.computed.filter still results in the view rendering all cards again

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help you without seeing more of your code. Can you reproduce the behavior in a JsBin?